# Java Keylistener broke

Tags: java, swing

I've been lately working on building a game, working on Key Listeners for now and the part 
"JTextField KeyCodeT = new JTextField("KeyCode:")" is where im getting and error at,
ERROR: "Cannot find symbol", thanks in advance

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Key1 extends Applet implements KeyListener {

    // A Text field that will display the key code
    JTextField KeyCodeT = new JTextField("KeyCode:");
    public Key1(){
        KeyCodeT.addKeyListener(this); // listends for key inputs in the text field
        KeyCodeT.setEditable(false); // disallow user input into the text field
        add(KeyCodeT); // add the text field to the screen
        setSize(300,300); // set the screen size
        setVisible(true); // show the window on screen
    }
    // called when the key is pressed down
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed!!!");
    }
    // called when the key is released
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Released!!!");
                KeyCodeT.setText("Key Code:" + e.getKeyCode()); // displays the key code in the text box

    }
    // called when a key is typed
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Key1 key = new Key1();
    }

    public void init() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        setBackground(Color.black);
        g.drawLine(8, 8, 492, 8);
        g.drawLine(8, 292, 492, 292);
        g.drawLine(8, 8, 8, 292);
        g.drawLine(492, 8, 492 , 292);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(8, 8, 485, 285);


    }
}
```

Comment: You're not importing `javax.swing.*;`

Comment: `import javax.swing.JTextField;` add this line or press ctrl+shift+o

Comment: Can you please post the whole error message?

Comment: ah, thnx :D i was wondering what was wrong

Comment: thnx msrd0 for the reformatted edit and both of you Kai and hovercraft :)

Comment: Your code has other problems: mixing AWT components (Applet) with Swing components, ... you will want to check out the tutorials a bit.

Comment: Have any links or places for good tutorials on it?